# Can i return a value instead of a view from my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

I would like to return the id of a newly created object for my ajax call instead of returning the view associated with the controller method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
render :text => @your_object.id
```

and then cast your `responseText` to integer in the javascript handler if needed.

Answer (score 1):

yes , you can .

```
render :text=> "the text that you want to return"
```